# How to display element from an array

Tags: reactjs, next.js, comments, sanity

In the below image there is an array given to me on doing console.log

[Array on doing console.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2OVLI.png)

The name of the array is commentData

if i do commentData.name i get the name

but when i do commentData.replyoncomment.Rname or commentData.replyoncomment[0].Rname

i get undefined even on commentData.replyoncomment

how do i solve this problem

if you need anything else ask me.

Update:

Thats how i turned commentData to an array

```
const convert = JSON.stringify(comment)
    const comments = Object.values(JSON.parse(convert))
    const commentData = comments
```

when i do commentData.name or commentData.commment

it give me the name/comment

but when i do commentData.replyoncomment i get undefined.

see the first image to understand better

on running this i get

```
{JSON.stringify(commentData)}
```

[[{"_createdAt":"2022-08-07T14:34:40Z","_id":"dqDIn547oWb3s2Y4OEwhMK","comment":"sdfanj akf js","name":"nkfndm nj","replyoncomment":[]},{"_createdAt":"2022-08-07T03:13:01Z","_id":"SD6gTXwnOmN4hstl5nkSbH","comment":"hello, I'm the admin of the webstie","name":"Mian Mohid Naeem","replyoncomment":[{"Rcomment":"gfdhhh","Rname":"gff","_createdAt":"2022-08-07T10:17:33Z"},{"Rcomment":"print("Hello world")","Rname":"programmer","_createdAt":"2022-08-07T03:13:40Z"}]}]]

anything else you need to see in the code ask me...

Comment: Isn't `commentData` an array? So you probably need to access each elements by their indexes. i.e. `commentData[0]` means the first element of `commentData` array. You access the elements inside arrays by their indexes, and access objects by the property names.

Comment: commentData[0] send this error Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {_createdAt, _id, comment, name, replyoncomment}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Comment: You should provide a minimal reproducible example. If you are rendering `{commentData[0]}` in your code it will throw an error because you CANNOT render data objects in react. You should convert them to string using `JSON.stringify`. For example `return <pre>{JSON.stringify(commentData, null, 4)}</pre>`

Comment: i want to render replyoncomment inside commentData

Comment: commentData is an array because i'm using in map function whereas i guess replyoncomment is acting as an object

Comment: As I said, you cannot render an array or an object directly inside React. I cannot help you unless you provide an example of your code. A mock value for your object and your code. But I'm sure you can definitely find the problem by debugging your code or logging values of variables after each statement.

Comment: `commentData` is an array that contains another array in its first position. If you want to access the first nested object, you'll have to do `commentData[0][0].replyoncomment[0].Rname`.

Answer (score 0):

You should map the commentData.replyoncomment to, cause it is an array too, and React can't render arrays.
So nest an additional map to the commentData.replyoncomment.
I was willing to help you, if you have any more questions, ask me.

Comment: map not working i guess it is acting as an object

Comment: try to console.log the commentData and see is it an array